# WPF Instantly change image source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have managed to work out how to change an image in my WPF form programatically, but I am really struggling to work out how to do it instantly. I have a GUI that reports on the progress of a number of processes, the below code works to change the image:

```
cacheBuilderStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox-complete.png"));
```

But this does not update the image instantly and I am at a loss as to how I force a redraw of the GUI. I have tried both of these but again neither seems to have any affect:

```
        cacheBuilderStatus.InvalidateVisual();
        cacheBuilderStatus.UpdateLayout();
```

I have even tried this to no avail:

```
        BitmapImage cbImage = new BitmapImage(); //(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        cbImage.BeginInit();
        cbImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
        cbImage.UriCachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
        cbImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        cbImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        cbImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png");
        cbImage.EndInit();
```

If anyone can help me understand how to achieve this I will be very grateful.

Thank you.

Edit: The XAML for the image in question is this:

```
            <Image x:Name="cacheBuilderStatus" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="20" Source="Resources/checkbox.png"/>
```

And the code in the background looks like this:

```
        // Reset progress images
    private void resetStatus()
    {
        BitmapImage cbImage = new BitmapImage(); //(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        cbImage.BeginInit();
        cbImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
        cbImage.UriCachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
        cbImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        cbImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        cbImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png");
        cbImage.EndInit();

        cacheBuilderStatus.InvalidateVisual();
        cacheBuilderStatus.UpdateLayout();

        cacheBuilderStatus.Source = cbImage;
        ciUserStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        accessCiUserStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        configItemStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        enumerationsStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        serviceOfferingStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        workItemStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        websiteStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
        appPoolStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox.png"));
    }


    // Buttons event handlers
    // Restart portal
    private void primaryToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Result variables
        string serviceRestartResult;
        bool cIUserResult;
        bool accessUserWIResult;
        bool configurationItemsResult;
        bool enumerationResult;
        bool serviceOfferingResult;
        bool workItemResult;
        string websiteRestartResult;
        string appPoolRestartResult;

        // Pull timeout variables from app.config
        serviceStatusChangeTimeout = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("serviceStatusChangeTimeout"));
        websiteStatusChangeTimeout = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("websiteStatusChangeTimeout"));

        // Get current DateTIme for LastModified tests
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();


        // Reset status images
        resetStatus();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        // Service restart
        serviceRestartResult = MidTier.ServiceRestart(serviceStatusChangeTimeout);
        if (serviceRestartResult == "Success")
        {
            // If success set service status icon to completed image
            cacheBuilderStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox-complete.png"));
        }
        else
        {
            // If fail set image to failed red cross, display error text and error text margin to 5 and height to Auto.
            cacheBuilderStatus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Resources/checkbox-error.png"));
            displayErrorText(serviceRestartResult);
        }
```

Comment: "But this does not update the image instantly" It should. Are you probably doing this in a loop or some other blocking operation in the UI thread?

Comment: Post cacheBuilderStatus declaration / XAML.

Comment: The images you switch are always the same or do they are built when you change them? How did you bind the Image in Xaml? maybe you just need to se the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged and raise correctly the property changed event for the property bound to the image. Or if the images are always the same, you can use a converter and instead of changing the image change the underline value

Comment: I have edited the original question, there are operations in the UI thread that could block it but I would have expected it to step through each action rather than to get caught up and it not happen. This is my first ever app though so my knowledge of threading is non-existent.

Comment: If the problem is that your UI is blocked by a long operation, my usual workaround is creating a sort of "DoEvents" to let the UI be updated even if the best practice would be to set the long operations in a thread different from the UI thread. But if your images are managed by the code inside the thread you will have some cross thread problems updating the UI. That is why, if the background operation blocks my UI anyway and the user must wait for it to complete I prefer the "DoEvents" approach.

Comment: Well currently everything is taking place in the one thread, which is why I thought that the images would update automatically when told to. But the resetStatus method is called before any of the long blocking methods so I do not understand why the GUI does not change to have all clear checkboxes before it gets locked up again. Do you think that moving these other methods to a background thread would be worth trying?

Comment: The UI won't update as long as it is in the `primaryToggleButton_Checked` method, especially when you call `Thread.Sleep(5000);`. Use a `DispatcherTimer` or a `BackgroundWorker` or a `Task` to update the UI in the background. Make sure to call back into the UI thread by `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` when you're not using DispatcherTimer.

Comment: Ok that fits with the behaviour that I have seen, could you please explain why that is the case? I understand why calling Thread.Sleep(5000) would cause it (that was an old experiment) but I don't understand why a method in the primary thread would not update the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to change the image looks fine and should update right away. The problem I assume your having is that your processing some information on the UI thread and therefore it does not update.

Your processing should always be moved to a background thread otherwise you lock the UI thread till your done and it cannot update.

For example if you do this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"e:\icons\transfer1.ico"));
}
```

It will update right away. But if you do processing in there like so it will not:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"e:\icons\transfer1.ico"));
    Thread.Sleep(5000); //simulate doing stuff
}
```

So instead do the processing on a different thread like so:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"e:\icons\transfer1.ico"));

    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Do work here
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the problem.

Comment: You sir are blessed.